# Why are username+something@gmail.com addresses not valid anymore?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, usability, email

Today I logged in to stackoverflow and saw that my gravatar was again a "monster" and not my gravatar pic. I went to gravatar and the avatar was working fine.

I was using a username+stackoverflow@gmail.com address, (I really love the + addresses in gmail) and when I swichted it back to just username@gmail.com (which is also registerd at gravatar, as main account) the proper gravatar picture appeared. I tried to put the + address again to see if it was still not working, but now I got a "email address not valid" error...

So why are username+whatever@gmail.com emails not valid anymore?

Comment: Jeff has some 'splaining to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using username+unicorn@gmail.com, and it *seems* to be working for me. Is that just my browser cache? Have I lost my unicorn?

Comment: weird.. its letting me do it again.. but now I LOST my unicorn... i mean, gravatar.. and yes, i DO have username+stackoverflow@gmail.com properly set in gravatar..

Comment: hmmmm looks like it ws MY cache.... I just deleted it and now my gravatar is on... it weird...

Comment: @bangoker - well I can see your gravatar, and your e-mail is currently +stackoverflow... seems OK?

Comment: yeah, I dunno what happend.. maybe a little glitch and i was to fast to pull the ask-a-question trigger, but yeah, after deleting my cache I could see my gravatar as well. Thank you for the quick respond though!

Comment: @bangoker, accept this answer please!

Comment: The cache doesn't explain the error message reported in the question.  @bangoker: You really did see that "not valid" message?